# remove character from macro parameter

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to create a macro to replace the for-loop

I want it to work like this:

```
f(var, start, Eend)
```

where var is the name of the loop variable, the start is the value where it begins and end, the value where it stops. The E is a symbol that can exist or not. If it exist, it is =

my macro is actually like this:

```
#define f(var, s, e) for(int var = s, kx = (s<e? 1 : -1); var != e; var += kx)
```

but this definition cannot afford = yet, so I want to extend it like this:

```
f(i, 10, =15) cout<<" "<<i;
output: 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

**My question is if it's possible to remove the first char of the Eend argument of macro.**

I can discover if it's equal using

```
#Eend[0] == '='
```

but after I cant use Eend to compare with s and find out if I must use ++ or --

This is what I want:

```
#define f(var, s, Eend) 

for(int var = s, kx = s<end? 1:-1, LIM = #Eend[0] == '='? end+kx : end; var!=end; var += kx)
```

where end is Eend without the '=' (if it exists)

Comment: Instead of a macro, just define a range object.

Comment: I'm used to this macro... I just wanna improve it

Comment: if end is just a number, how about sg like `atoi(&#Eend[1])`?

Comment: Also, if you're willing to use `=` or `<` (and not skip it), you might just overload the operators on some type (lhs) to something fancy.

Answer (score 1):

For your macro question you can simply define two macros, with slightly different (hopefully mnemonic) names.

E.g., if I understand the intention correctly,

```
#define xf(var, s, e) for(int var = s, kx = (s<e? 1 : -1); var != e; var += kx)

#define f(var, s, e) for(int var = s, kx = (s<e? 1 : -1), e2 = e + kx; var != e2; var += kx)
```

If the redundancy of that is not palatable, then you can express them in terms of a third common implementation macro.

---

Doing this without a macro is more work, but you only have to do the definition work once.

And you avoid possible name collisions for the macro.

E.g. it can go like this:

```
enum From { from };
enum To { to };
enum To_before { to_before };

class Sequence
{
private:
    int first_;
    int after_;
    int delta_;

public:
    class Iter
    {
    friend class Sequence;
    private:
        Sequence const* p_seq_;
        int             current_;

        Iter( Sequence const& seq )
            : p_seq_( &seq )
            , current_( seq.first_ )
        {}

        Iter( Sequence const& seq, int const current )
            : p_seq_( &seq )
            , current_( current )
        {}

    public:
        friend auto operator==( Iter const& a, Iter const& b )
            -> bool
        { return a.current_ == b.current_; }        // UB if not same sequence.

        friend auto operator!=( Iter const& a, Iter const& b )
            -> bool
        { return a.current_ != b.current_; }

        auto operator*() const
            -> int
        { return current_; }

        auto operator++()
            -> Iter&
        {
            current_ += p_seq_->delta_;
            return *this;
        }

        auto operator++( int )
            -> Iter
        {
            Iter result{ *this };
            current_ += p_seq_->delta_;
            return result;
        }
    };

    auto begin() const -> Iter { return Iter{ *this }; }
    auto end() const -> Iter { return Iter{ *this, after_ }; }

    Sequence( int const first, int const last, bool inclusive = true )
        : first_( first )
        , after_( last )
        , delta_( first <= last? 1 : -1 )
    { if( inclusive ) { after_ += delta_; } }

    Sequence( From, int const first, To, int const last )
        : Sequence( first, last, true )
    {}

    Sequence( From, int const first, To_before, int const last )
        : Sequence( first, last, false )
    {}
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using Seq = Sequence;
    for( int const i : Seq{ from, 10, to, 15 } ) { cout << i << ' '; }
    cout << endl;
    for( int const i : Seq{ from, 15, to, 10 } ) { cout << i << ' '; }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for( int const i : Seq{ from, 10, to_before, 15 } ) { cout << i << ' '; }
    cout << endl;
    for( int const i : Seq{ from, 15, to_before, 10 } ) { cout << i << ' '; }
    cout << endl;
}
```